# how to select a particular version of python from command prompt

Tags: terminal, version

By default, I know MAC uses the python version 2.7.10. I have python 3.7 installed. I became sure of it by typing

`python3 --version`

in terminal which shows 3.7.2.

I want to use python's secret module which is available for python 3.3x above. Now, when I type `python` in my terminal, I get the python 2.7x interpreter but I want to select python 3.7.2 as interpreter. How can I select the python 3.7.2 interpreter version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both python 2 and python 3 are installed, `python` runs python 2 by default and `python3` runs python 3. If only python 3 is installed, then `python` runs python 3. `python` and `python3` are just shortcuts to the full path to the binary. Run `which python` and `which python3` to see what they are. Therefore, typing the full path or creating an [alias](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) would be one way to select the interpreter that you want.
Another way would be running a specific version of python in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). That way you also have complete control over the specific versions of packages that you might use.